# How to store a variable to be used by a then promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using an API to download some data and I want to store it. I want to make multiple calls using different dates and store all the data together, as well as the date in question, like this:

```
let rankJson = [];
let rankExport = [];
let ranks = [];

function add_weeks(date, n)  {
    return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + (n * 7)));      
};
for (i = startingDate; i < new Date(); i = add_weeks(i,1)) { 
    // This loops starts at some date I define and adds a week until it reaches a date in the future. 

    let activeYear = i.getFullYear();
    let activeMonth = monthNames[i.getMonth()];
    let activeDay = i.getDate();
    API.function({year: activeYear.toString(), month: activeMonth, day: activeDay.toString()}).then((res) => {

        // This is an API call (its an NPM/Node API) that returns a promise. I then want to store the resulting json array and add the date (i) as new values for each object like so: `

        rankJson = JSON.stringify(res);
        ranks = JSON.parse(rankJson);
        ranks.forEach(function(value){
            rankExport.push({
                "teamName" : value.team.name,
                "teamId": value.team.id,
                "position" : value.place,
                "points" : value.points,
                "posChange" : value.change,
                "rankDay" : activeDay,
                "rankMonth" : i.getMonth() + 1,
                "rankYear" : activeYear,
            })
        });
```

In essence, I want all of the responses from the API to be stored in one array (don't need it to be in order) with the right date value. Problem is, I don't know how to pass the date variables so that the correct value is applied. When I pass it like this, it seems to be using the last iteration (i.e. a date in the future). I've also found this to be a bit finicky, mostly because I obviously don't have a lot of experience with promises.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: `let` gives you block scope. So `for (let i = startingDate; ..... )`. No need to change anything else.

Comment: Not sure I did it right, but I made that change and the code still doesn't do what I need it to.

Comment: By writing `for (let i = startingDate; ..... )`, `i` is given "block scope" within `for () {...}` so when you need `i` in the `.then()` callback, it will be the correct `i`. Otherwise, `i` will be hoisted to function scope and will be `i` of the last iteration of the loop when accessed from the `.then()` callback. This is an oft-reported issue that people have with asynchronous operations in javascript for loops. Before the introduction of `let`, we had to form closures (as per Dave's answer) but that is no longer necessary (in most current js environments). `let` solves the issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Yeah, not sure why, but that's exactly what I tried based on your comment and it wasn't working properly. Not sure what's the issue.

Comment: You have done something horribly wrong! :-)

Comment: If you say so! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)/[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(function(i) {
    let activeYear = i.getFullYear();
    let activeMonth = monthNames[i.getMonth()];
    let activeDay = i.getDate();
    API.function({
        year: activeYear.toString(),
        month: activeMonth,
        day: activeDay.toString()
    }).then((res) => {
        // ...
    });
})(i);
```

The issue right now is that the API call is asynchronous, so by the time you get to the `.then`, the values of `activeYear`, `activeMonth`, `activeDay`, and `i` will all have been updated to the last value.  By wrapping it in a closure each iteration of the loop will have its own scope.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this code by adding all objects to an array and then use `Promise.all`

```
var promisses=[]
for (let i = startingDate; i < new Date(); i = add_weeks(i,1)) { 
  promisses.push({year: i.getFullYear().toString(), month: monthNames[i.getMonth()], day: i.getDate().toString()})}
 Promise.all(promisses.map(o=>API.function(o))).then((p) => {
 p.forEach(res=>{
  rankJson=JSON.stringify(res)
  ranks = JSON.parse(rankJson);
    ranks.forEach(function(value){
        rankExport.push({
            "teamName" : value.team.name,
            "teamId": value.team.id,
            "position" : value.place,
            "points" : value.points,
            "posChange" : value.change,
            "rankDay" : activeDay,
            "rankMonth" : i.getMonth() + 1,
            "rankYear" : activeYear,
        })
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: That is a useful tip, but it doesn't solve the query completely. At least as far as I am understanding the code, I still can't seem to be able to pass the right dates into the right api response. Basically, this now makes sure all the calls I am making are the right ones (which I think was already the case, but this definitely makes it simpler) but I still can't store the right active date as a value in the array I am building at the end (rankExport). But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @Marino Molina  Yes this code allows you to pass all your api calls to `Promise.all `and then it returns a single Promise, an array of all resolved promises, now you just have to iterate through this arrays and extract the values you want and assign them to `rankJson `,`ranks `....

Comment: I have updated the code to include the rest of how you could arrange your data, it shloud look like the code above

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time. I realize I might be drowning in a glass of water here, but even with the extended code you shared it still doesn't quite work. The issue is activeDay, activeYear, etc. are still defined somewhere, and by the time the promise resolves, they are not the right ones. I am not sure how to link the right dates with the right elements.

Comment: You're welcome, maybe the issue is in the order of execution could you add `async/await` like this `Promise.all(Arrpromisses.map(async o=> await API.function(o)))` and see if that solves the problem